# Sony TV remote control over UPnP

Tags: google-tv, sony

I'm developing a plugin for MediaPortal that switches a TV into 3D mode whenever a 3D movie is detected. The code is written in C#.

I had also support for Sony TVs (BRAVIA) that now doesn't seem to work with a BRAVIA XBR-55X850A.

I was using the following web-request for registering with the TV:

```
"http://" + ip + "/cers/api/register name=DeviceName&registrationType=initial&deviceId=MediaRemote";
```

Then I sent commands over UPnP via the IRCC-service "urn:schemas-sony-com:service:IRCC:1".

This works with some BRAVIA models, but not with the BRAVIA XBR-55X850A.

Is there any information available, what exactly is necessary for a successful pairing with the TV?

Comment: Sorry, but documentation for the Sony BRAVIA TV APIs is not currently publicly available.